# Move selected option at top of drop down menu

Tags: html, jquery, drop-down-menu, dropdown

Script

```js
var tkopt = {"c":"C","cs":"C#","d":"D","ef": "Eb","e":"E","f":"F","fs":"F#","g":"G","af":"Ab","a":"A","bf":"Bb","b":"B"};  
 $(document).ready(function(){     
   var sel = $("#tlist");
   $.each(tkopt, function(index, value){
     $("<option/>",{ value : index, text : value}).appendTo(sel);
   });
   $(function() {
     $("#tlist").val('e');
   });
 });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<select id="tlist">
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

The options provided here is just musical root keys. Here I made option E as selected option. Now I need the options above E to be appended at end of the option lists. i.e. option C should follow B at down, which is followed by C#, so on upto option Eb which follows option D. Please help me with jquery code.

Comment: Note that `$(function()` is same thing as `$(document).ready(function()` so not needed inside the `ready`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
$(this).find("option:selected").index()
```

to get the currently selected option's index, then move all the ones before it to the end in one step:

```
sel.find("option").filter((i, e) => $(e).index() < idx).appendTo(sel);
```

Updated snippet:

```js
var tkopt = {"c":"C","cs":"C#","d":"D","ef": "Eb","e":"E","f":"F","fs":"F#","g":"G","af":"Ab","a":"A","bf":"Bb","b":"B"};

$(document).ready(function() {
  var sel = $("#tlist");
  $.each(tkopt, function(index, value) {
    $("<option/>", {
      value: index,
      text: value
    }).appendTo(sel);
  });

  sel.change(function() {
    var idx = $(this).find("option:selected").index();
    sel.find("option").filter((i, e) => $(e).index() < idx).appendTo(sel);
  });

  $("#tlist").val('e').change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<select id="tlist"> </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:selected` selector along with [`prevAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) to get the collection prior to the selected one then append that whole collection all in a simple one line operation within a change event handler

```js
var tkopt = {"c":"C","cs":"C#","d":"D","ef": "Eb","e":"E","f":"F","fs":"F#","g":"G","af":"Ab","a":"A","bf":"Bb","b":"B"};

var sel = $("#tlist");

$.each(tkopt, (k, v) => sel.append(new Option(v, k)));

sel.change(() => sel.find(":selected").prevAll().appendTo(sel));
// trigger initial change on page load after setting default value
sel.val('e').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<select id="tlist"> </select>
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting. But there is a problem. From above example, option C is not following option B.I want it like that. Thanks for optimizing my script code.

Comment: Are you saying there needs to be a sort order also? That was not clear in question and objects do not have a guaranteed sort order either

Comment: No idea what that means and the sorting is not clear in the question. What are the specific sorting rules?

Comment: If E is selected, the drop list should in this order E, F, F#, G, Ab, A, Bb, B, C, C#, D, Eb

Comment: I didn't use the word 'sorting'.Sorry for that.